# Ошибка в webview на iOS 17

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

При вызове `var myYandexMap = new ymaps.Map(...params...)` в webview на iOS 17 возникает следующая ошибка:

> **TypeError: Argument 1 ('shader') to WebGLRenderingContext.shaderSource must be an instance of WebGLShader**

На остальных версиях iOS все работает стабильно... Mobile Safari UI/WKWebView

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить? Спасибо!